# express.static doesn't serve static files(images) if put under 'img' directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to setup a proxy server using express, and below is my configuration for serving static files.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/^\/assets/', express.static('/path/to/root/public'));
```

As per the above config, whenever path starts with /assets is see, files from http://localhost:3000/public should be served. It works fine for all files, except in one scenario.

Say, I have a directory by name 'img' under public and current path is /assets/img, files (images in my case) are not getting served. But, if i rename directory to 'images', it is working as expected.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `express.static()` needs to be passed a local directory path, not a URL.  It serves resources from the local file system, not from other systems.

Comment: yeah @jfriend00, my bad!, I was using local path in my app, i edited the question now. Thanks!

Comment: To help you with this kind of question, we need to see three things: 1) The exact tag in your HTML that contains the resource you're trying to load, 2) The full path location on your hard drive of the resource that you want to be served for that tag, 3) The actual path you are passing to `express.static()`.  Only then, can we advise what is wrong or what needs to be corrected.  I don't want to see pseudo-code examples - I want to see the actual values you are using.

Comment: Why are you calling this a proxy server?  That isn't what this is at all.  It's just a web server, serving static resources.  I ask because I wonder if you're trying to do something other than just serve static resources.